# How do I solve this "RuntimeError" while calling a python object with the "read" method?: << Maximum recursion depth exceeded >>

Tags: ubuntu, recursion, odoo

I am working on Odoo. I am trying to read fields value with `read()` method.

This is my code:

```python
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if isinstance(ids, (list, tuple)) and not len(ids):
        return []
    if isinstance(ids, (long, int)):
        ids = [ids]
    reads = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['name','parent_id'], context=context)
    res = []
    for record in reads:
        name = record['name']
        if record['parent_id']:
            name = record['parent_id'][1]+' / '+name
        res.append((record['id'], name))
    return res
```

Error occur:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the `read` method, use `browse` or `search` methods instead. Check if this works for you:

```python
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    # [...]

    res=[]
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        name = record.name
        if record.parent_id:
            name = record.parent_id[0] + ' / ' + name
        res.append((record.id, name))
    return res
```